# When is a non-static const data member more useful than a const static one?

Tags: c++, static, constants

In C++ there are static and non-static `const` data members.
When I want a constant, I always make it `static` because it does not make sense to have multiple copies (one per each instance of the class) if the item cannot be modified. I would like to know why are there non-static `const` members?

Comment: Using `static` puts this variable in the data-section. You might want to avoid that if you're using only local objects, and your stack is large enough to accommodate them even if they are slightly larger (due to the additional non-static member variable).

Comment: @barakmanos Is that related to specific hardware or is there a tangible advantage even with code that will run on a PC?

Comment: It is compiler-implementation dependent (i.e., not defined by the C++ language standard). I don't understand what you mean by "even with code that will run on a PC".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A `static const` applies to the class
2. A `const` applies to the object

E.g.

```
class Verticies {
    public:
       const int colour;
       static const int MAX_VERTICIES = 100;
       Point points[MAX_VERTICIES];
       Verticies(int c) : colour(c) { }
       // Etc
};
```

Here `MAX_VERTICIES` applies to all objects of type `Verticies`. But different objects could have different colours and that colour is fixed on construction

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
       MyClass(int val): myVal(val) {}
       const int myVal;
};
```

In this small example, `myVal` is readable by everyone without a getter method, but it's not modifiable as soon as MyClass is instantiated.

You just declare data types as `const` if you want to make sure they are not modified later on.

Because `myVal` is not `static`, it can have different values for every different instance of `MyClass`. If `myVal` would be `static`, it would have the same value for every instance and would not be assignable by the constructor.

Take the following example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(int val) : myConst(val) {}
        void printVars() {
            cout << "myStatic " << myStatic << endl;
            cout << "myConst " << myConst << endl;
        }

        static const int myStatic;
        const int myConst;
};

const int MyClass::myStatic = 5; //Note how this works without 
                                 //an instance of MyClass

int main()
{
    MyClass ca(23);
    MyClass cb(42);
    cout << "ca: " << endl;
    ca.printVars();
    cout << "cb: " << endl;
    cb.printVars();
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
ca: 
myStatic 5
myConst 23
cb: 
myStatic 5
myConst 42
```

The following would result in a compilation error because the variables are const:

```
ca.myConst = 11;
ca.myStatic = 13;
```

Comment: But what's the advantage over `static const int myVal`?

Comment: @barakmanos That every instance can have its own *different* constant value for `myVal`. It is set once when initializer list of the constructor is executed, after that the semantics are that it can't be changed. But every instance can have its own value.

Comment: @Marius: Got it. Cool answer (assuming that it's compiling without an error).